# How can I forward/alias/delegate a function to a method?

Tags: rust

I want to forward a function to a method in another module, without repeating all the type annotations, and without manually passing the parameters over. How would I do this?

```
mod other_mod;

static client: other_mod::Client = other_mod::Client::new();

async fn search = client.search; // How to do this here?
```

`mod other_mod`:

```
pub struct Client();

impl Client {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        Self()
    }    

    pub async fn search(&self, query: &str) -> Result<Vec<SearchResultItem>> { ... }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no way to do that in Rust.

Comment: [My job here is done](https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/my-job-here-is-done)

Comment: That's a shame. Go does this too, but I assumed it was just because Go is needlessly verbose.

Comment: For people finding this in search of a compiler optimization barrier: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60720419/7204912

Answer (score 3):

The main issue with your example, is the `static Client`:

- It cannot be created, because Rust does not allow life before or after `main`.
- It cannot be mutated without using `unsafe`, for thread-safety reasons.

---

You can create the `Client` if you make its `new` function `const`.

Then you can make it `pub` and there is no need to forward the function at all, users can simply call `CLIENT.search`.

```
pub static CLIENT: other_mod::Client = Client::new();
```

---

You can also refactor `other_mod` to expose the `search` function as free-standing:

```
pub async fn search(query: &str) -> ...
```

And then forward it in your own:

```
pub use other_mod::search;
```

---

There are simply no facilities to forward methods on globals; Rust is harsh on global variables, because they open all kinds of issues, so I doubt that such syntactic sugar will come any time soon.