# How to declare a function without implementing it?

Tags: rust

I'd like to compare the assembly of different implementations of functions but I don't want to implement certain functions, just declare them.

In Rust, forward declaration are typically unnecessary, due to the compiler not needing the functions in order to resolve them (unlike in C). However, is it possible to do something equivalent to a forward declaration?

Comment: For a reason: I'd like to bench some functions in [godbolt](https://rust.godbolt.org) but I don't want to implement certain functions, just delcare them.

Comment: Are you asking for `extern` block? This might lead to linker errors, however.

Comment: `extern` seems to look good, but that needs an `unsafe` block to use. Is there a way not to use `unsafe?

Comment: If the function isn't called in your code, you can define it with `unimplemented!()` body. Could you share an example of the expected code?

Comment: Please note: `panic!()` will mark every code after it as unreachable and therefore optimize it away. That's not what I want. https://rust.godbolt.org/z/SK8SEL

Comment: "I'd like to bench some functions" - you want to look at the generated assembly is what you mean?

Comment: @SebastianRedl yes. I'd like to compare different implementations of functions.

Comment: What about an empty function with `#[inline(never)]`?

Comment: @rodrigo does it work? If yes, post an answer :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you declare your function as `#[inline(never)]` you will get a function call instruction to prevent further optimizations.

The main limitation is that your function must not be empty after optimizations, so it must have some side effect (thanks to @hellow that suggests using `compiler_fence` instead of `println!`).

For example, this code ([godbolt](https://rust.godbolt.org/z/cg3Tmu)):

```
pub fn test_loop(num: i32) {
    for _i in 0..num {
        dummy();
    }
}

#[inline(never)]
pub extern fn dummy() {
    use std::sync::atomic::*;
    compiler_fence(Ordering::Release);
}
```

Will produce the following assembly (with `-O`), that I think you need:

```
example::test_loop:
        push    r14
        push    rbx
        push    rax
        test    edi, edi
        jle     .LBB0_3
        mov     ebx, edi
        mov     r14, qword ptr [rip + example::dummy@GOTPCREL]
.LBB0_2:
        call    r14
        add     ebx, -1
        jne     .LBB0_2
.LBB0_3:
        add     rsp, 8
        pop     rbx
        pop     r14
        ret
```

plus the code for `dummy()` that is actually empty:

```
example::dummy:
        ret
```

Comment: `extern "C"` is another option so you don't even have to provide a definition.  [How to disable LLVM optimisations for rust in Godbolt (for asm education purposes)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72564785) shows an example.

Comment: @PeterCordes instead of `extern "C"` I would recommend `extern "Rust"` ;)

Comment: @hellow: Oh, that works?  Then sure.  I barely know Rust, just occasionally dipping a toe in, and `extern "C"` was all that was mentioned on https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/keyword.extern.html which came up in my google search for "rust declare extern function".

Comment: The `extern "Rust"` is great. I was worried that using a `extern "C"` would include some cross-language code. A small ergonomic issue is that you need to use `unsafe` to call any extern function.

Answer (score 5):

It's not possible to forward-declare functions. There is only a single declaration for any given entity in Rust.

However, you can use the `unimplemented!()` and `todo!()` macros to quickly fill in the bodies of functions you don't want to implement (yet) for some reason. Both are basically aliases for `panic!()` with specific error messages.

Comment: I thought about that as well, but the compiler will optimize the panic call and mark every code afterwards as unreachable. https://rust.godbolt.org/z/SK8SEL

Comment: So? The compiler is right, the code afterwards is unreachable. If you actually want to run something, you can't just not implement it.

Comment: Indeed, but in C you can just forward declare the function and the generated assembly will be a function call and then will continue normally.

Comment: Is black_box what you're looking for? https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/hint/fn.black_box.html

Comment: @nnnmmm is that usable with functions? It's unstable as well (which is worse than `unsafe` ;) ) in my case, because I'd like to compare different stable compilers

Comment: `extern "C"` does allow a forward declaration without a definition.  [How to disable LLVM optimisations for rust in Godbolt (for asm education purposes)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72564785) shows an example of using it to make asm you can look at.  https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/keyword.extern.html  (@hellow)

Comment: @PeterCordes That sounds like something you should post as an answer.

Comment: It is in my answer, on the highly related but not quite duplicate question I linked.  I didn't want to close this one as a duplicate (or that newer one as a duplicate of this), but I also didn't want to copy/paste large parts of my answer.  I ended up commenting here, which isn't ideal either.

Answer (score 2):

Declare a trait and have your function and its signature in there.
eg.

```
pub trait Summary {
  fn summarize(&self) -> String;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you elaborate it more, e.g. add some example code? Also, do you think it is what OP (me) inteded to do?

Comment: Perhaps I mis-undertood the request. You sought too declare a function without providing the body. That is exactly what I did.  And I gave an example. In Object oriented languages you can declare a method and the implement it later. Traits in rust provide that ability.

Comment: The goal here is similar to [How to remove "noise" from GCC/clang assembly output?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38552116) - you want the compiler to see a function call it doesn't know how to inline, so any reference args have to actually exist in memory, and so on.  And so the function will be non-leaf. 
 Like this C example: https://godbolt.org/z/M5KxPfqWT