# How to disable LLVM optimisations for rust in Godbolt (for asm education purposes)

Tags: assembly, optimization, rust, llvm

I am learning about rust and asm, and using godbolt for this.

I have a program that looks like:

```
pub fn test() -> i32 {
    let a = 1;
    let b = 2;
    let c = 3;
    a + b + c
}
```

And I would expect the output to look something like

```
example::test:
        subq    $16, %rsp
        movl    $1, (%rsp)
        movl    $2, 4(%rsp)
        movl    $3, 8(%rsp)
        movl    (%rsp), %eax
        addl    4(%rsp), %eax
        addl    8(%rsp), %eax
        addq    $16, %rsp
        retq
```

But I actually get:

```
example::test:
        mov     eax, 6
        ret
```

This is useless when trying to demonstrate stack allocation, addition etc.

I am using the compiler flags: `-Z mir-opt-level=0 -C opt-level=0 -C overflow-checks=off`

So the MIR isn't optimising away the additions. The MIR output is:

```
// WARNING: This output format is intended for human consumers only
// and is subject to change without notice. Knock yourself out.
fn test() -> i32 {
    let mut _0: i32;                     // return place in scope 0 at /app/example.rs:2:18: 2:21
    let _1: i32;                         // in scope 0 at /app/example.rs:3:9: 3:10
    let mut _4: i32;                     // in scope 0 at /app/example.rs:6:5: 6:10
    let mut _5: i32;                     // in scope 0 at /app/example.rs:6:5: 6:6
    let mut _6: i32;                     // in scope 0 at /app/example.rs:6:9: 6:10
    let mut _7: i32;                     // in scope 0 at /app/example.rs:6:13: 6:14
    scope 1 {
        debug a => _1;                   // in scope 1 at /app/example.rs:3:9: 3:10
        let _2: i32;                     // in scope 1 at /app/example.rs:4:9: 4:10
        scope 2 {
            debug b => _2;               // in scope 2 at /app/example.rs:4:9: 4:10
            let _3: i32;                 // in scope 2 at /app/example.rs:5:9: 5:10
            scope 3 {
                debug c => _3;           // in scope 3 at /app/example.rs:5:9: 5:10
            }
        }
    }

    bb0: {
        StorageLive(_1);                 // scope 0 at /app/example.rs:3:9: 3:10
        _1 = const 1_i32;                // scope 0 at /app/example.rs:3:13: 3:14
        StorageLive(_2);                 // scope 1 at /app/example.rs:4:9: 4:10
        _2 = const 2_i32;                // scope 1 at /app/example.rs:4:13: 4:14
        StorageLive(_3);                 // scope 2 at /app/example.rs:5:9: 5:10
        _3 = const 3_i32;                // scope 2 at /app/example.rs:5:13: 5:14
        StorageLive(_4);                 // scope 3 at /app/example.rs:6:5: 6:10
        StorageLive(_5);                 // scope 3 at /app/example.rs:6:5: 6:6
        _5 = _1;                         // scope 3 at /app/example.rs:6:5: 6:6
        StorageLive(_6);                 // scope 3 at /app/example.rs:6:9: 6:10
        _6 = _2;                         // scope 3 at /app/example.rs:6:9: 6:10
        _4 = Add(move _5, move _6);      // scope 3 at /app/example.rs:6:5: 6:10
        StorageDead(_6);                 // scope 3 at /app/example.rs:6:9: 6:10
        StorageDead(_5);                 // scope 3 at /app/example.rs:6:9: 6:10
        StorageLive(_7);                 // scope 3 at /app/example.rs:6:13: 6:14
        _7 = _3;                         // scope 3 at /app/example.rs:6:13: 6:14
        _0 = Add(move _4, move _7);      // scope 3 at /app/example.rs:6:5: 6:14
        StorageDead(_7);                 // scope 3 at /app/example.rs:6:13: 6:14
        StorageDead(_4);                 // scope 3 at /app/example.rs:6:13: 6:14
        StorageDead(_3);                 // scope 2 at /app/example.rs:7:1: 7:2
        StorageDead(_2);                 // scope 1 at /app/example.rs:7:1: 7:2
        StorageDead(_1);                 // scope 0 at /app/example.rs:7:1: 7:2
        return;                          // scope 0 at /app/example.rs:7:2: 7:2
    }
}
```

And the LLVM IR output is:

```
define i32 @_ZN7example4test17h2e9277ab15e59fbdE() unnamed_addr #0 !dbg !5 {
start:
  ret i32 6, !dbg !10
}

attributes #0 = { nonlazybind uwtable "probe-stack"="__rust_probestack" "target-cpu"="x86-64" }
```

So it is at the MIR->LLVM level when the additions are optimised out.

How can I prevent this?

Thanks!

*Note*

If I use a tuple, the optimisation doesn't happen. e.g

```
pub fn test() -> i32 {
    let a = (1,2,3);
    a.0 + a.1 + a.2
}
```

becomes:

```
example::test:
        subq    $16, %rsp
        movl    $1, (%rsp)
        movl    $2, 4(%rsp)
        movl    $3, 8(%rsp)
        movl    (%rsp), %eax
        addl    4(%rsp), %eax
        addl    8(%rsp), %eax
        addq    $16, %rsp
        retq
```

Comment: So this is due to constant folding/propagation.  It isn't clear to me (having scanned through the relevant parts of the [Rustc Guide](https://rustc-dev-guide.rust-lang.org/mir/optimizations.html) and the linked [MCP](https://github.com/rust-lang/compiler-team/issues/319)) whether they should be disabled by `-Z mir-opt-level=0` or not and therefore whether this is a bug.  Perhaps one for an issue in the rustc repo?

Comment: Note that llvm performs constant folding during ir building, not just during optimization/codegen.

Comment: @Aiden4 Yes, but not from local variables (`alloca`). It requires mem2reg. Is building without optimizations enough for you?

Answer (score 2):

There is the [`black_box`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/hint/fn.black_box.html) hint that prevents the computation from happening at compile time.

Note that it is only available on nightly, at the time of writing.

```rust
#![feature(bench_black_box)]

pub fn test() -> i32 {
    let a = std::hint::black_box(1);
    let b = std::hint::black_box(2);
    let c = std::hint::black_box(3);
    a + b + c
}
```

```
example::test:
        sub     rsp, 12
        mov     dword ptr [rsp], 1
        mov     rax, rsp
        mov     eax, dword ptr [rsp]
        mov     dword ptr [rsp + 4], 2
        lea     rcx, [rsp + 4]
        add     eax, dword ptr [rsp + 4]
        mov     dword ptr [rsp + 8], 3
        lea     rcx, [rsp + 8]
        add     eax, dword ptr [rsp + 8]
        add     rsp, 12
        ret
```

Compiled with `rust nightly` and `-C opt-level=3`.

https://rust.godbolt.org/z/rMWhao11W

Answer (score 1):

Pass mutable references to them to some other function (or inline asm) to force them to have memory addresses.  One hack for declaring a function without defining it is `extern "C"`.

```
extern "C" {
    fn ext(x: &i32);   // void ext(const int *x);
}

pub fn test(a: i32, b: i32) -> i32 {
    let c = 3;
    unsafe{ ext(&b); }
    //dummy(&c, &a);   // alternative, declare as non-inline an use std::hint::black_box
    a + b + c
}
```

With `-C opt-level=0 -C overflow-checks=off` [**on Godbolt**](https://rust.godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:rust,selection:(endColumn:25,endLineNumber:19,positionColumn:25,positionLineNumber:19,selectionStartColumn:5,selectionStartLineNumber:19,startColumn:5,startLineNumber:19),source:%27%23!!%5Bfeature(bench_black_box)%5D%0A%0Aextern+%22C%22+%7B%0A++++fn+ext(x:+%26i32)%3B+//+void%0A%7D%0A%0Apub+fn+test(a:+i32,+b:+i32)+-%3E+i32+%7B%0A++++let+c+%3D+3%3B%0A++++unsafe%7B+ext(%26b)%3B+%7D%0A++++//dummy(%26c,+%26a)%3B%0A++++a+%2B+b+%2B+c%0A%7D%0A%0A/*%0A%23%5Binline(never)%5D%0Apub+extern+fn+dummy(_a:+%26i32,+_b:+%26i32)+%7B%0A++++//use+std::sync::atomic::*%3B%0A++++//compiler_fence(Ordering::Release)%3B%0A++++std::hint::black_box(_a)%3B%0A++++std::hint::black_box(_b)%3B%0A%7D%0A*/%0A%0A%0Apub+fn+test2(a:+i32,+b:+i32)+-%3E+i32+%7B%0A++++let+c+%3D+3%3B%0A++++a+%2B+b+%2B+c%0A%7D%0A%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Rust+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:35.208047553726566,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:nightly,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:2,lang:rust,libs:!(),options:%27-C+opt-level%3D0+-C+overflow-checks%3Doff%27,selection:(endColumn:12,endLineNumber:17,positionColumn:12,positionLineNumber:17,selectionStartColumn:12,selectionStartLineNumber:17,startColumn:12,startLineNumber:17),source:1,tree:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27rustc+nightly+(Rust,+Editor+%231,+Compiler+%232)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),k:49.326718639262936,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:nightly,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:rust,libs:!(),options:%27-C+opt-level%3D3%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1,tree:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27rustc+nightly+(Rust,+Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:50.673281360737064,l:%274%27,m:71.02952913008778,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:64.79195244627343,l:%272%27,m:100,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4), the compiler spills *both* args to memory around the function call.

```
example::test:
        push    rax                          // align the stack and reserve 8 bytes
        mov     dword ptr [rsp], edi
        mov     dword ptr [rsp + 4], esi
        lea     rdi, [rsp + 4]               // &b
        call    qword ptr [rip + ext@GOTPCREL]  // function call  -fno-plt 
style
        mov     eax, dword ptr [rsp]         // reload a and b
        add     eax, dword ptr [rsp + 4]
        add     eax, 3                       // constant-propagation for c
        pop     rcx                          // dealloc stack space with a dummy pop
        ret
```

Without disabling optimization, LLVM as expected saves/restores a call-preserved register to keep `a` across the function call.

```
example::test:
        push    rbx                          // save a call-preserved reg
        sub     rsp, 16

        mov     ebx, edi                     // use it to hold a
        mov     dword ptr [rsp + 12], esi    // spill b
        lea     rdi, [rsp + 12]              // and pass a pointer to it
        call    qword ptr [rip + ext@GOTPCREL]
        mov     eax, dword ptr [rsp + 12]
        add     eax, ebx
        add     eax, 3

        add     rsp, 16                      // epilogue
        pop     rbx
        ret
```

---

Or to block constant-folding specifically, use function args instead of constants.  As in: [How to remove "noise" from GCC/clang assembly output?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38552116)

```
pub fn test2(a: i32, b: i32) -> i32 {
    let c = 3;
    a + b + c
}
```

But even with `-C opt-level=0 -C overflow-checks=off` on Godbolt,
Rustc still doesn't spill/reload to stack space like clang -O0 would.

```
example::test2:
        mov     eax, edi
        add     eax, esi
        add     eax, 3
        ret
```

(`opt-level=3` of course uses an LEA instead of MOV+ADD, but still uses a separate add of the constant 3 to optimize for latency instead of throughput on CPUs like Skylake where a 3-component LEA has 3 cycle latency instead of 1.  Unlike Alder Lake where `lea eax, [rsi+rdi+3]` is 1 cycle latency, and would be 2 with a scaled index.  Or 2 cycles for that on Zen or Alder Lake E-cores, so break-even with separate LEA/ADD but fewer uops.  https://uops.info/)

---

#### `#[inline(never)]`

This was suggested on [How to declare a function without implementing it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60702335/how-to-declare-a-function-without-implementing-it) as a way to get a non-inline function call.  We can use `std::hint::black_box` as suggested by @Finomnis to actually use the args and force the caller to materialize a value in memory when it passes a reference.

Uncomment it on the Godbolt link above to try it out.

```
#![feature(bench_black_box)]

pub fn test(a: i32, b: i32) -> i32 {
    let c = 3;
    dummy(&c, &a);
    a + b + c
}


#[inline(never)]
pub extern fn dummy(_a: &i32, _b: &i32) {
    //use std::sync::atomic::*;
    //compiler_fence(Ordering::Release);   // make the function non-empty even without args
    std::hint::black_box(_a);
    std::hint::black_box(_b);
}
```